# Does android add extra active area around submit buttons?

Tags: android, html, css, usability, tap

Android seems be to be increasing the clickable area of a submit button on an HTML form I'm working on. It's as if there's about 25 pixels to the right of the submit button that are also tap-able. This is problematic because, in my design, to the right of the submit button is an `<A>` element with an event handler bound to it. Tapping the `<A>` often submits the form instead of firing the event handler. I'm doing most of my testing in Browerstack and some on real hardware. The problem exhibits in (virtual) devices with lower screen widths (e.g. 320px), and seems to be there in Android 2.3 and 4. The same pages in iPhone (4s, iOS6) and Blackberry (v7) don't exhibit the problem.

[Here's a CodePen example](http://codepen.io/simondell/pen/wltGA), and a [single file version](http://demo.expressionworks.co.uk/android-extra-targetarea/index.html) of the same code for easier viewing on mobile

Has anyone else seen this? Is it a feature? A bug - either in Android or in my code?

Comment: In case I wasn't clear, this extra hit-area isn't visible. It doesn't take up space, doesn't push aside any of the surrounding elements. The hit area behaves as though the button has `position:relative; padding-right: 30px; z-index:100;` applied, but there is no actual positioning applied to any of the elements concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried applying a reset.css to it? It seems to be an android webkit issue.

Also, try to use 40px areas for tap buttons.

Comment: I agree 40px touch areas would be better. The design I have to work to, agreed by the client, produced by the 3rd party, before I came onto the project, doesn't work to those recommendations so there's not much scope there. I will be pushing for some changes.

Comment: I've chosen this as the answer because it's sensible advice, and I wanted "closure" on this question. I couldn't implement it, for the reasons stated.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the reset.css stylesheet provided by meyerweb.com. It removes (almost) all styling that browsers would apply, but you may find you need to rework a lot of css and put a lot of stuff in such as `<h1>` tags.

[CSS Tools: Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: That's a useful suggestion, and a derivative of that file is already in the project.

Comment: Following up a bit further, I thought I'd better check what was in the reset you linked to and how it might be different from the file I was using. [Mayer's reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) doesn't specify anything that would control spacing around input controls. It doesn't even include the string "input" at all. The version of the file I have is more explicit, controlling `-webkit-appearance`,`box-sizing` as well as margins and padding. I can't see what would be causing this other than some Android-specific rules about touch-able areas around submit buttons.